# How to disable radio buttons according to the DB query result?

Tags: php, jquery, fuelphp

```
<?php foreach ($types_show as $size): ?>
    <td class='size_rdo'><?php echo Form::radio('radio_size', $value)?></td>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

This will display some radio buttons,I want to send the `$value` to the php. if there is the value in DB, the radio button is able, otherwise set it to disable.

I write some Pseudocode below,thanks for answering.

```
 $(':radio[name=radio_size]').each(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/management/order/get_size",
            data: {radio_size:radio_size},
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                $(this).attr("disabled",true);
             }
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that FuelPhp allow you to do it in PHP with adding attributes on the Form helper (I don't know this framework, but it seems to work like another framework I know, [see the documentation](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/form.html#/method_radio)).

```
<?php foreach ($types_show as $size): ?>
    <td class='size_rdo'>
        <?php if($value) // Here I don't understand what you want to test on your 
                         // condition, you must correct it depending of your needs
             // If the value is not good, then add the disabled attribut
             echo Form::radio('radio_size', $value, array('disabled'))?>
         else // If the value is the good one, just continue like you did
             echo Form::radio('radio_size', $value)?>
    </td>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Then you don't need Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you really want an ajax call for every radio button. It would be better to do one call, and then loop and check for every radio...

anyway, you have to pass the $(this)

```
$(':radio[name=radio_size]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/management/order/get_size",
            data: {radio_size:radio_size},
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                $this.attr("disabled",true);
             }
            },
        });
    });
```